# Proving $\sum_{cyc}(1+\sin A)^{\cos A}\le {\sum_{cyc}}(1+\sin A)^{\cos B}$ for $\triangle ABC$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

I need some help :D

> For $\triangle ABC$, prove that
> $$\sum_{cyc}(1+\sin A)^{\cos A}\leq{\sum_{cyc}}(1+\sin A)^{\cos B}.$$

I'm really stuck with this problem because I haven't learned much about trigonometric inequality. At first I thought it was multiplication then we can solve it quite easily by returning it to log form and using permutation inequality but I was wrong.

Everyone can post imagination. Thanks very much!

Comment: Is this from the Romanian Mathematical Magazine?

Comment: @冥王Hades it looks like it. I found it in a book and it says source is romanian

Comment: @Question It seems the reverse inequality is true. Can you check it?

Comment: @RiverLi oh sorry so much it was my fault. the inequality must be the opposite. i wrote it wrong.if you have a solution pls help me

Comment: @RiverLi i fixed it

Comment: @RiverLi a long but great answer thank you so much

Comment: @Question You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some thoughts**:

The desired inequality is written as
$$\mathrm{e}^{X} + \mathrm{e}^Y + \mathrm{e}^Z
\ge \mathrm{e}^U + \mathrm{e}^V + \mathrm{e}^W \tag{1}$$
where
$$X = \cos B \, \ln(1 + \sin A), \quad Y = \cos C\, \ln(1 + \sin B), \quad Z = \cos A \, \ln(1 + \sin C)$$
and
$$U = \cos A \, \ln(1 + \sin A), \quad V = \cos B\, \ln(1 + \sin B), \quad W = \cos C \, \ln(1 + \sin C).$$

WLOG, assume that $C = \min(A, B, C)$.

Let $p_1\ge p_2\ge p_3$ be the rearrangement of $X, Y, Z$.
Let $q_1 \ge q_2 \ge q_3$ be the rearrangement of $U, V, W$.

We split into two cases.

**Case 1**: $A \ge B \ge C$

We have
$$\cos C \ge \cos B \ge \cos A. \tag{2}$$

We have
$$\sin A \ge \sin B \ge \sin C \ge 0. \tag{3}$$
(*Note*: If $A \ge \pi/2$, then $\sin A = \sin(\pi - B - C) = \sin (B + C)$.)

Using (2) and (3), we have
$$Y \ge V, \quad Y \ge W, \quad X \ge U, \quad X \ge V. \tag{4}$$

We have
$$V \ge U. \tag{5}$$
(*Proof*: If $A \ge \pi/2$, we have $V \ge 0 \ge U$.
If $A < \pi/2$, using $B \ge \pi/4$, since $x\mapsto \cos x\, \ln(1 + \sin x)$ is strictly decreasing on $[\pi/4, \pi/2]$, we have $V \ge U$. We are done.)

From (4) and (5), we have
$$p_1 \ge Y \ge q_1 \tag{6}$$
and
$$p_1 + p_2 \ge X + Y \ge \max(U + V, U + W, V + W) = q_1 + q_2.\tag{7}$$

From (2) and (3), by the rearrangement inequality, we have
$X + Y + Z \ge U + V + W$ i.e.
$$p_1 + p_2 + p_3 \ge q_1 + q_2 + q_3.\tag{8}$$

Using (6)-(8), by [Karamata's inequality](https://www.detailedpedia.com/wiki-Karamata%27s_inequality), we have
$$\mathrm{e}^{p_1} + \mathrm{e}^{p_2} + \mathrm{e}^{p_3}
\ge \mathrm{e}^{q_1} + \mathrm{e}^{q_2} + \mathrm{e}^{q_3}.$$

Thus, (1) is true.

**Case 2**: $B \ge A \ge C$

We have
$$\cos C \ge \cos A \ge \cos B. \tag{9}$$

We have
$$\sin B \ge \sin A \ge \sin C.\tag{10}$$
(*Note*: If $B \ge \pi/2$, we have $\sin B = \sin (\pi - A - C) = \sin (A + C)$.)

Using (9) and (10), we have
$$Y \ge U, \quad Y \ge V, \quad Y \ge W. \tag{11}$$

From (11), we have
$$p_1 \ge Y \ge q_1. \tag{12}$$

Using (9) and (10), we have
\begin{align*}
 &Y + Z - U - W \\
 ={}& \cos C \, [\ln(1 + \sin B) - \ln(1 + \sin C)] - \cos A \, [\ln(1 + \sin A) - \ln(1 + \sin C)]\\
 \ge{}& \cos C \, [\ln(1 + \sin B) - \ln(1 + \sin C)] - \cos A \, [\ln(1 + \sin B) - \ln(1 + \sin C)]\\
 ={}& (\cos C - \cos A)[\ln(1 + \sin B) - \ln(1 + \sin C)]\\
 \ge{}& 0. \tag{13}
\end{align*}

Using (9) and (10), we have
\begin{align*}
 &X + Y - U - V\\
 \ge{}& \cos B\, \ln(1 + \sin A) + \cos A\, \ln(1 + \sin B)\\
&\quad - \cos A\, \ln(1 + \sin A) - \cos B\,\ln(1+\sin B)\\
 \ge{}& 0 \tag{14}
\end{align*}
where we use the rearrangement inequality.

We have
$$U \ge V. \tag{15}$$
(*Proof*: If $B \ge \pi/2$, we have $U \ge 0 \ge V$.
If $B < \pi/2$, using $A \ge \pi/4$,
since $x\mapsto \cos x\, \ln(1 + \sin x)$ is strictly decreasing on $[\pi/4, \pi/2]$, we have $U \ge V$. We are done.)

Using (13)-(15), we have
$$p_1 + p_2 \ge \max(X + Y, Y + Z) \ge 
\max(U + W, U + V, V + W) = q_1 + q_2. \tag{16}$$

From (9) and (10), by the rearrangement inequality, we have $X + Y + Z \ge U + V + W$ i.e.
$$p_1 + p_2 + p_3 \ge q_1 + q_2 + q_3. \tag{17}$$

Using (12), (16) and (17), by [Karamata's inequality](https://www.detailedpedia.com/wiki-Karamata%27s_inequality), we have
$$\mathrm{e}^{p_1} + \mathrm{e}^{p_2} + \mathrm{e}^{p_3}
\ge \mathrm{e}^{q_1} + \mathrm{e}^{q_2} + \mathrm{e}^{q_3}.$$

Thus, (1) is true.

We are done.